# $S_4$ as a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles, general-linear-group

I am trying to find a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$, which is isomorphic to $S_4$. Our teacher gave us a hint: we should look at matrices with first column $(1, 0, 0)^T$.

But what is the next step?

My guess would be that there is some relation between this fact and the fact that $S_4$ is isomorphic to $GA(2,2)$ (general affine group), but I don't know how to proceed futher.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so you should try and prove that the subgroup of ${\rm GL}_3(2)$ consisting of matrices with that first column is isomorphic to the group ${\rm GA}(2,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The affine group $GA_n(K)$ (for any field $K$) is embedded into the linear group $GL_{n+1}(K)$ by:
$$[x\mapsto Ax+b]\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\b&A\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I know this does not correspond to your teacher's hint, approved by @DerekHolt , but I cannot find what they had in mind. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250086

Comment: If instead you make the embedding into the inverse transpose of the matrix then it corresponds exactly to the teacher's hint.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you!